# Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I already tried to Invalidate/Cache and restart

also tried to remove .gradle and gradle file..
but this problem still shows up.

> Error:Unable to find method
>   'com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension.getTestVariants()Lorg/gradle/api/internal/DefaultDomainObjectSet;'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's
>     dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network
>     connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies
>     and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle
>     build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may
>     solve this problem. Stop Gradle build
>     processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a
>     third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in
>     the project or the version of Gradle requested by the
>     project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can
>   also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Any thoughts?

Your help will be appreciated Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `.gradle` in the project directory or the user home directory? A full clean might be to do `git clean -dfx` and `rm -rf ~/.gradle` (assuming you don't have a `gradle.properties` file there). Then kill off any daemons or run with --no-daemon

Comment: Thanks. already solved this problem.
The file happened to be corrupted.

Comment: @EmmanuelDeiparine I'm also facing the same issue. Will you please tell how you solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: **Build>Clean Project** resolved my issue.

Comment: Please check this. It may help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304945/gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt-this-sometimes-occurs-after-a-network/54305292#54305292](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304945/gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt-this-sometimes-occurs-after-a-network/54305292#54305292) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error. I solved this error by change version of gradle distribution in gradle-wrapper.properties (you can find list of distribution in https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

> gradle-wrapper.properties

For the example my old version gradle distribution:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5-all.zip
```

My new version gradle distribution:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.7-all.zip
```

By changed this version, android studio will download the new of gradle disrtribution and sync with the project.
[This is the location of gradle-wrapper.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APSrE.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset the gradle to an older version which you can load correctly. Change the distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties in gradle scripts. And this error can be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I think your version of kotlin-gradle-plugin is low; you can try to update your  kotlin-gradle-plugin in project/build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'
    classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.2'
    classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.2-4'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete /.gradle/ folder and /gradle/ folder and reimport.  Or in the case of IntelliJ, you can click the Gradle Tool window and click Refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Change the `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties` in `gradle scripts`. And this error can be solved.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to manually download the gradle, and clear gradle distributions in `C:\Users\myUserName\.gradle\wrapper\dists`.. Nothing worked.

The only thing worked for me is to install java JDK 11, then set it in

```
File > Project Structure -> SDK location -> JDK location
```

[image]

And then redownload the gradle distribution;

I am using Android Studio v4.2, so it may differ for lower versions.

Answer (score 0):

*in the gradle-wrapper.properties*
I changed the *"https"* to *http* and everything worked perfect

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, with the following symptoms:

1. I tried to delete the `.gradle` folder from project - it doesn't work.
2. I tried use an old gradle version, but studio forced me to use `gradle-3.3`, so it confused me a long time.
3. I noticed the tips unzip exception:

   > `java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file`

   I tried to unzip the file by hand, it said it couldn't unzip, so the problem must have happened in the download process.

**My solution:**
I copied the file `gradle-3.3-all.zip` from my colleague who managed to build successfuly，and replaced mine in this path:

```
.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```