# Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.) for Version 4.10.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

I got this issue after updating the android plugin.

Please help.

I tried to change the gradle version to 4.6(distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip) and its working too, but I want to use the recommended gradle-4.10.1 (distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip) version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well I resolved the issue.

Remove the ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.1-all folder and then rebuild the project in android studio.

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.1-all
```

This removes the corrupted or partially downloaded gradle-4.10.1-all.

This is working for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, deleting and downloading gradle-4.10.1-all again did not solve my problem and I keep getting `Cannot Resolve Symble R`

Comment: did not work for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
in this image we will show Gradle wrapper class its show about our current project Gradle version ;

---

**C:\Users*username*.gradle\wrapper\dists**

*delete the dists folder*

download ant GitHub project and run it
     - in this case, the android studio will download necessary files.
     - and Gradle files too it about 135MB size.
after successfully download run the GitHub project and after this run your local project.
yeah, the android studio will run normally.........

Comment: Please explain what issue are you facing.
the Question is too confusing. This website is about getting help about errors you are facing during coding. If you don't explain what issue are you facing then it would be very difficult for us to help.